# Handling multiple fork()s in c

Tags: c

I'm struggling to understand this concept. Let's say I want to run 3 concurrent processes (threads are not an option, this is an assignment).

I would do:

```
int main(){
    fork();
    if (getPid() == -1) { //this is the parent
        fork(); //make a third process
    } else if (getPid() == 0) { //child process
    //do child things
    }
```

So from what I've learned the parent pid is -1. And there's two children, both with PID 0?

So then the "parent" can spawn as many children as possible, correct? They will all do child things.

What if I want to do 3 different things? How do I track the PID's so that I have 3 unique
 ones?

as per the comments - is this how it's done?

```
pid_t child2Pid;
pid_t child1Pid = fork();
switch /*if getPid is wrong what do I put here?*/ {
case -1: //parent
    child2Pid = fork(); //create another child
case child1Pid :
    //do what child1 would do
case child2Pid :
    //do what child2 would do
```

Comment: You need to check the return value of `fork()`, not `getPid()`.

Comment: 4th year university of course! I realize that it could be a switch/case

Comment: I think you misunderstand something. When you start a child with fork(), it doesn't start from the first line of main() - it starts from the point of fork(). It's **not** like CreateProcess() on Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pid_t child1, child2, child3;
if ((child1 = fork()) == 0)
{
    // first child stuff goes here
    _exit(0);
}
if ((child2 = fork()) == 0)
{
    // second child stuff goes here
    _exit(0);
}
if ((child3 = fork()) == 0)
{
    // third child stuff goes here
    _exit(0);
}
// we are in the parent, we have the PIDs of our three
// children in child1, child2, and child3
```

Comment: won't child1 additionally fork child2 and child3? Why is `(child2 = fork()) !=0`?

Comment: The `_exit(0)` prevents the child from running any further code. The `fork` call returns `0` in the child.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is that you enter fork() once, but leave it twice - once in the parent, once in the child. In the parent, fork() returns the child's PID, in the child, fork() returns 0. -1 means error and there is no child.

So when you call fork(), look at the return value. Like this:

```
  if(fork() > 0) //We're in the parent, and a child was spawned
      fork(); //Spawn another.
```

This will create three processes. Error handling omitted.

Answer (score -1):

**
    int main()
    {
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < 3;i++)
    {
        pid = fork();
    }

```
if(pid == 0)
{
    printf("child\n");        
}
else if(pid > 0)
{
    printf("parent\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

you can use pid_t = fork() to record the value,and select what you do by the value.**